# How to split a column into some columns with cells like type dict?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, split

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' :[{'id':'0','num':10 } ,{'id':'1','num':20 },{'id':'2','num':30 }]})
```

I want to get

```
   id  num
0   0   10
1   1   20
2   2   30
```

I wanted to remain only numbers and letters and then apply `split` 
But I cann't make it

```
df['a'] = df['a'].replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', regex = True)
df
```

or

```
df['a'].str.strip('{').astype(str)
```

or

```
df['a'].str.replace('\{','')
```

all options are incorrect. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

Just convert the series to a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(df.a.tolist())

  id  num
0  0   10
1  1   20
2  2   30
```

If the values in `a` are strings that can be converted to dictionaries use `ast`

```
import ast
pd.DataFrame(df.a.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)).tolist())
```

Answer (score 3):

Using your df + `apply`

```
df.a.apply(pd.Series)
Out[559]: 
  id  num
0  0   10
1  1   20
2  2   30
```

Comment: thanx I click your answer but @djk47463 was firrst

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to djk47463's answer (which should be accepted) is

```
df["id"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x : x["id"])
df["num"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x : x["num"])
df.drop(columns=["a"], inplace=True)
```

**EDIT (timing)**

```
lst = [{"id":i, 'num':(i+1)*10} for i in range(10000)]
df =  pd.DataFrame({"a":lst})

%%timeit -n10
a = df.a.apply(pd.Series)
1.98 s ± 26.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n100
a = pd.DataFrame(df.a.tolist())
9.01 ms ± 292 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n100
a = pd.DataFrame(df.a.values.tolist())
8.75 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n100
df["id"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x : x["id"])
df["num"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x : x["num"])
5.33 ms ± 257 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And given you already have a list you can play with that before create a dataframe

```
%%timeit -n100
a = pd.DataFrame([[l["id"], l["num"]] for l in lst], columns=["id", "num"])
3.6 ms ± 111 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thanx I click your answer but @djk47463 was firrst

Comment: @djk47463 is for sure the best as it's general.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' :[{'id':'0','num':10 } ,{'id':'1','num':20 },{'id':'2','num':30 }]}['a'])
print df

   id  num
0  0   10
1  1   20
2  2   30
```

replace `{'a' :[{'id':'0','num':10 } ,{'id':'1','num':20 },{'id':'2','num':30 }]}`

with `{'a' :[{'id':'0','num':10 } ,{'id':'1','num':20 },{'id':'2','num':30 }]}`**['a']**

Answer (score 0):

Have you realized that you could easily do?

```
pd.DataFrame([{'id':'0','num':10 } ,{'id':'1','num':20 },{'id':'2','num':30 }])
```

The timing is comparable to djk47463's answer. So I guess it's running the same command under the bonnet, but after check the type.

```
lst = [{"id":i, 'num':(i+1)*10} for i in range(int(10000))]

%%timeit -n100
a = pd.DataFrame(lst)
9.94 ms ± 196 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```